# Mapbox re-routing remove all intermediate waypoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am using `'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.18'` for my turn by turn navigation.

It works fine if I create route with `MBRouteOptions`.

But when the navigation re-route it lost track of all intermediate waypoints. This was working earlier.

Comment: I would doubt this contains the necessary [mcve] to be answerable. Is there any other information that someone would need to replicate the problem?

Comment: @halfer please follow below thread for more information https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/1536